# How to solve $x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)....(x-999)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

How to solve $x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)....(x-999)$?

I'm calculating the probability of $1000$ multicast group having different address. Multicast address space is $2^{28}$.

So I tried to calculate it like this.

$$(2^{28} / 2^{28}) ((2^{28} - 1)/ 2^{28}) ... ((2^{28} - 999)/ 2^{28})$$

$$2^{28} (2^{28} - 1)(2^{28} - 2)... (2^{28} - 999) / (2^{28})^{1000}$$

Substitute $2^{28}$ with $x$,

$$x(x-1)(x-2)...(x-999) / x^{1000}$$

So, where do I go from there?

I just have no idea how to simplify the numerator

Comment: It is not clear.

Comment: You don't "solve" expressions, you solve equations. For example, do you seek $x$ for which the first expression equals $x^{1000}$?

Comment: no x is 2^28, I am trying to simplify it so I can work with the big number

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If $x = r \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1000}}$, then the expression $$x(x-1)\cdots(x - 999) = \frac{r!}{(r - 1000)!}.$$  So if $r = 2^{(28)},~$ then simply substitute $2^{(28)}$ for $r$ in the above expression.

Comment: When $N:=2^{28}$ legal addresses exist, $k:=1000$ examples can be chosen in $N^k$ ways, of which $k!\binom{N}{k}=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(N-j)$ contain no repetitions. This occurs with probability$$\frac{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(N-j)}{N^k}=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(1-j/N).$$If $k\ll N$ (as in this case), this can be approximated as $\exp\left(-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}j/N\right)$, which I leave you to simplify if it's useful to you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I have failed my math teacher :''

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can get a good approximation by using the large-$x$ [asymptotic expansion](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.E13) of the ratio of two gamma functions. In particular,
$$
\frac{{x(x - 1)(x - 2) \cdots (x - 999)}}{{x^{1000} }} = \frac{{\Gamma (x + 1)}}{{x^{1000} \Gamma (x - 999)}} \approx 1 - \frac{{{\rm 499500}}}{x} + \frac{{{\rm 124583708250}}}{{x^2 }}.
$$
Use this with your large $x=2^{28}$.